# Using downloadtask with url

Tags: swift, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I'm trying to use downloadTaskWithURL() but upgrading it to the latest version: downloadTask and I'm trying to run this code snippet but it won't compile.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
let downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with url: endpointURL, completionHandler: { (url: URL!, response: URLResponse!, error: Error!)

    if (error == nil) {
        //some code 
    }
})

downloadTask.resume()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the message that the compiler is giving you for failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several errors: your function signature is wrong (`url` is only used inside the function body, when calling it, the name of the input parameter is `with`) and you missed `in` after specifying the closure variables. Find the code which compiles without an issue below:

```
let downloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: endpointURL, completionHandler: { url, response, error in
    if error == nil {
        //some code 
    }
})

downloadTask.resume()
```